# g++ with big std::array freezes

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, std, freeze

I wrote a very small program:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

const unsigned int NUM = 500;

void simple()
{
    using namespace std;
    array<tuple<float, float, float>, NUM> vectors;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `g++ -std=c++0x`.

This version works just fine, *but* if I increase `NUM` to maybe 50,000,000, g++ uses 90% CPU and my system freezes entirely.

I understand that a program can crash *during execution* if there is not enough stack memory. But why would the compiler freeze *during compilation*?

Is this a bug in g++ or does the compiler need to allocate stack memory during compilation for some reason?

Comment: I think it's because you went over the range for int.

Comment: Compile to assembler (-S) with `NUM=500`. Do it again with `NUM=5000`, and compare the files. What changed? If there is 10x as much tuple default constructor code, the answer in your case is that g++ is busy emitting 50000000 (probably inlined) default constructors.

Comment: Interesting. What version of g++?

Comment: @drum `std::size_t` is an unsigned integer so it would be small again.

Comment: @drum, 50,000,000 is well within the range of int

Comment: Thanks for the info. I miscounted the 0s.

Comment: OK, I tried it myself - changing `NUM` makes a trivial change to the code (just a different offset to the stack pointer and a different argument to memset, as you'd hope), but a non-trivial difference to compile time. Perhaps it's generating lots of code and then optimizing it out ...

Comment: If it helps: On Windows, with MinGW, g++ 4.6.2, the compiler crashes with the following error: `cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes`

Comment: @Useless why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: Because I don't really have an answer yet ...

Comment: This appears to be [GCC bug# 59659](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59659) which should be fixed in 4.9.

Comment: Now _that's_ an answer.

Comment: [Compiles and runs fine on gcc 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97575ad4bb46c88f), so it appears that the problem is in fact the cited bug.

Comment: Thank you, I will install gcc 4.9 as soon as possible and will hopefully be able to continue with my work.